# Java installation error on Debian 8

Tags: apt, oracle, debian-jessie, command, tutorial

I followed the instructions from this website:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-debian-8

When I install jre and jdk it says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
default-jdk is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

So I followed the instruction to the point:

> sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

After that it says:

```
    Building dependency tree 
    Reading state information... Done  
    E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer
```

And when I run 
java -version
or
javac -version

It says:

```
bash: java: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

This article you followed is outdated as the "PPA" it tries to add and use does not exist anymore. Worry not, I believe you are better off without Oracle's package anyway.

**So, how do you get Java?**
Simply install one of the so called `openjdk` packages.
You can get a list of them by using the command: `apt-cache search openjdk` and then using `sudo apt-get install PACKAGENAME`.
I believe you are looking for `openjdk-8-jdk`, which can be installed by using:
`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`.

These packages work just as well as the Oracle one did/does.

Here is an online list of these packages:
https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=openjdk&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all

Comment: Hmm when I do apt-cache search openjdk
I can only see openjdk-7 packages and not openjdk-8 packages
And when I run sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk it says:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-8-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'openjdk-8-jdk' has no installation candidate

Really wired :/

Comment: Oh shoot, sorry. Debian 8 is the "oldstable". You can install the OpenJDK 7 package, or use "Adopt OpenJDK": https://adoptopenjdk.net/installation.html#linux-pkg